# Inverter voltage signal pulses data

Tags: electrical-signal, data-request

We're performing analysis as a part of a project and we're looking for some data sources which we could use for our analysis. What we're looking for are specifically inverter voltage pulses which are used to run electric motors. Any idea where I could get such data ? (ideally in CSV or similar form)

Edit:
What I'm looking for is a voltage signal time series data from an inverter which is used to control electric motor and the data are acquired with DAQ system ideally with sampling rate greater than 1 MSps. When I say control electric motor, I'm referring to signals used to feed stator coils for out-runner electric motor

Comment: From a motor? With a data acquisition device (DAQ)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My apologies for missing info, it was modified. It should be hopefully clear now